# Django: order_by('?') has strange outcome

Tags: python, django, django-views

In django shell:

```
>>> queryset = Song.objects.all()
>>> a=queryset.order_by('?')
>>> queryset
[<Song: Up All Night>,  <Song: 1973>, <Song: The Luckiest>, <Song: Another Love>, <Song: Face the Sun>]
>>> a
[<Song: The Luckiest>, <Song: 1973>, <Song: Face the Sun>, <Song: Another Love>, <Song: Up All Night>]
>>> a[0].name
'1973'
```

you see, the last two outputs contradict each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `a[0]` (or just `a`) some more times. You'll notice it shuffles the elements randomly every time. This is because `a` points to the `queryset`, not a `list`.

To understand why the `queryset` reorders every time, imagine this scenario: You need to get all elements from a set in alphabetical order. However, elements are constantly being added to the set. If they're not placed in order every time you access the query set, you risk having a recently added element be out of order.

If you want to get a list of the elements in a random order (and not have them shuffling each time you grab an element) you could use

```
a = list(queryset.order_by('?'))
```